# php pdo comment page error

Tags: php, pdo

sorry for my English.

My knowledge about the database is very simple.

I have to come this code from a Forum.

My problem, when anyone writes a comment, it shows on all Website, when I to wish that it only to display on the File where it writes.

**I to try to solve this problem with....**

I have **Two Files**, one with the Php code, **code.php** then another where the comment is display, **comment.php**.

On **comment.php** file have top above,

```
include '/var/www/html/code.php';
```

and bellow where the comment display

```
<?php $object = new ClassProveContakt3("1");?>
```

On **code.php** top above, declare the properties to `$site`,

```
 private $site;
```

The **function __construct($site)** mit de parameter **$site**, I to call it with,

```
public function __construct($site) {


     $this->site->$site;
     ...
```

When updating the **comment.php** page, to come **Two** warning,

**1)**

> Trying to get property '1' of non-object in /var/www/html/code.php on line 35

On line 35 have `$this->site->$site;`

**2)**

> Undefined variable: site in /var/www/html/code.php on line 164

On line 164 have `$sth -> execute( array(':site' => $site ));`,

it is the function to conect to database, this function,

```
function getMessages()
{
    if ( ! $this -> dbh ) {
        $this -> getConnection();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM commentar WHERE site = :site ORDER BY datetime DESC";
    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare( $sql, array( PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY ));
    $sth -> execute( array(':site' => $site ));

    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    if ( false === $result ) {
        $this->reportPDOError( "fetchAll(ASSOC) failed", $sql );
    }
    foreach ($result as $message) {

 ?>


 <p><strong>From: </strong> <?=htmlspecialchars( $message['name'] ) ?>            
 <strong>at: </strong> <?=htmlspecialchars( $message['datetime'] ); ?></p>
 <p><?=htmlspecialchars( $message['message'] ); ?></p><hr>


<?php
    }    
  }
}
```

All Code from **code.php** is [here](https://repl.it/@122345676/kommentar1)

Can please someone help me with this problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "found" the solution, people give me the solution but I too to search...

**On comment.php**

In **comment.php** file have top above,

```
include '/var/www/html/code.php';
```

remove it.

and bellow where the comment display, change from

```
<?php $object = new ClassProveContakt3("1");?>
```

to

```
include_once '/var/www/html/code.php';
```

Because of used **include_once** and not **include** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49813618/11523795) to say why.

**On code.php**

In Line **163** change from

```
 $sth -> execute( array(':site' => $site ));
```

to

```
$sth -> execute( array(':site' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) );
```

Why $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ? , as php to [say](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) about **'REQUEST_URI'**, *The URI which was given in order to access this page*. I want that comment only to display on the File where it writes. It to say , when site = place where I'm .....write here.

In Line **183** change from

```
$Newobject = new ClassProveContakt3();
```

to

```
$Newobject = new ClassProveContakt3($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Why $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?, when the **comment.php** file call the **$Newobject** object, it is the [Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1788926/11523795) which send to **comment.php**

I thank all the people who help me with this problem!